# Accidentally removed System32\config

Tags: windows-10

I have booted a repair live usb (on my windows 10), and accidentally the whole `System32\config` folder.
Is there any chance to restore? or repair this?
Even windows repair and diagnose could not repair this.
Is there even a chance ... or I have to re-install windows?

Answer (score -1):

Windows 10 registry is located there, so it is the automatically generated backup (`C:\windows\System32\config\RegBack`).
Your user registry is not there, but in the user folder, so you wont have to repair the user afterwards.

This is a heavy problem, and you will most likely have to reinstall your system, however I think it is still possible to repair the system.

I'm not 100% sure this will work in Windows 10, though.

If you are making regular system restore points, there should still be a copy of the registry within the system restore point files which are located in `c:\system volume information`.

The theoretical way to repair your system is:

**I'd advise you to backup your data in any case **and** make a dd of your hard disk to another **in case you really need to boot that system for any reason** one before trying any further procedure

1. Restore the System32\config folder structure. You can use a repair DVD or another Windows 10 installation, it shouldn’t really matter, although I’d recommend to use a repair DVD to get the files.
2. Recover your registry files from the system recovery files. They should be located inside c:\system volume information folder
3. Place your folders inside the correct structure
4. Try to boot
5. If you can’t boot, try the automatic repair again.

The procedure on XP is detailed here. Please, note the folder c:\windows\repair doesnt exists anymore:

[Recover Xp registry from Registry Point](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307545/how-to-recover-from-a-corrupted-registry-that-prevents-windows-xp-from)

Another possibility is to use data recovery software such as GetDataBackFromNTFS or Recuva, however, if you've been trying to repair the damage and wrote something to the disk you may have already destroyed your files.

Also, [Windows 10 DaRT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-desktop-optimization-pack/dart-v10/) is allways a good tool to have around when trying to repair Windows systems. [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-desktop-optimization-pack/dart-v10/creating-the-dart-10-recovery-image) is a Microsoft's guide to build a DaRT 10 image, however, I'm sure you can obtain it in an easier way around the Internet, however, as it violated MS terms, I'm not allowed to share it here.

You should keep in mind that this is going to involve some work, and may affect future system stability. You have to consider how much work it would take to fully reinstall everything against the amount of work and further needed to recover the system. If you work on IT and in the future this may be useful to repair a client’s PC I recommend you to go ahead and try, though.

So, a short answer is: there are pretty good chances to recover your system if you have:

- A previous restore point stored.
- Access to a DVD install or a running windows 10 system and admin rights on its file system.
- R/W access your file system and its hidden protected folder `c:\system volume information` (with a liveCD like [SystemRescueCD](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/Download/) or DaRT, for instance)

If you dont have a restore point or a registry backup around you'll have to recover your registry using data recovery software or reinstall your system.

Comment: No, I don't have a restore point, I always delete them with CCleaner ..., and I checked `system volume information` is empty. I'm trying a system restore as we speak ... it will take some time ... if that did not work, I will try to get the `config` folder of another windows 10 installation.

Comment: If you have no restore points your only chance would be try to recover your registry files using Recuva or GetDataBack. Otherwise you have to reinstall your system. Please, some reputation would be appreciated :D